# how to set JXBrowser default foreground and background colors ?

Tags: jxbrowser

Any way to set default foreground / background colors ?

I am trying to use JXBrowser as packaged in TI's CCS ( Code Composer Studio )
- an eclipse clone, on RHEL7 Linux, under KDE .

I have set GTK apps to use the 'Adwaita-Dark' theme, which works for 
all other GTK using apps to set the default foreground and background colors - but not for JXBrowser / Chrome - the Menus and toolbar use the Adwaita-Dark
theme, but the browser frame tabs use black on white - it hurts my eyes!

I have also set the 'swing.properties' file in ${JRE_HOME}/lib to contain
 'swing.defaultlaf=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel' 
which usually makes Java applications use the GTK Adwaita-Dark theme also.

Please , could anyone advise how to get JXBrowser to honor the user's GTK  theme selection, or to change its default browser tab foreground / background ? 
Is there some theme file I can install in some location ? If so which / where?

Thanks in advance for any replies!

Answer (score 0):

JxBrowser embeds Chromium control that displays web pages. By default, the `about:blank` web page is loaded when you create a new tab. The reason why you see white background is that the `about:blank` web page has the white background. At the moment, there's no known solution to tell Chromium to change background color of the `about:blank` web page, so it's hard to suggest a solution or workaround for your case.

Comment: I don't think the issue is to do with 'about:blank' - 
The TI CCS application loads many JXBrowser tabs on startup, and 'about:blank' is not
one of them .

Comment: I installed Chrome Dev itself also in my search for an answer to this problem,
and it also does not honor the user's GTK theme settings.
I also discovered Chrome does not even support a user-defined CSS stylesheet anymore .  I then removed Chrome from the system, as
it is of no use if it cannot honor the user's color settings.
CCS supports a 'Dark' theme, which makes all of its other
windows display in white on dark-grey / black, EXCEPT the
JXBrowser windows - making it even more glaring .

Comment: I will try to rebuild JXBrowser with the default foreground
and background swapped and replace CCS's JXBrowser
with one that supports the user's selected color scheme.